# How can I get color in an example org block exported to a verbatim beamer environment

Tags: org-export, latex, beamer

I am trying to get some color in an example block exported to beamer by doing something like the following

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
case when \textcolor{red}{condition-1 then value-1}
     when condition-2 then value-2
     .
     .
     .
     when conditionn then value-n
     else value-z
 end
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

According to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370334/use-color-in-verbatim-environment) post on the tex stackexchange site, a verbatim enironment can get color by adding the commandchars argument, i.e.

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
a (black)
\textcolor{red}{b} (I want this letter to be red)
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get `commandchars` option set in the example block. I've tried adding a `#+ATTR_LATEX: :options [commandchars=\\\{\}]` above the example block, modifying the begin example line as `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE :options commandchars=\\\{\}`, `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE :commandchars \\\{\}`, and  `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE :options [commandchars=\\\{\}]` and none of that has worked. How should I get color in my example block. Also, is there some reading material somewhere where I can find how to properly pass options/keywords/attributes to org-mode for exporting purposes. The org mode manual hasn't exactly made a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question of how to add options to an example block, but I found a solution that gets me color in a verbatim block in case someone is looking to do that in the future:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options [commandchars=\\\{\}]
#+BEGIN_Verbatim 
 when condition-1 then value-1
     when \textcolor{red}{condition-2} then value-2
     .
     .
     .
     when conditionn then value-n
     else value-z
 end
#+END_Verbatim
```

I believe you have to include the `fancyvbr` package to get this to work.

Comment: This is the best you can do (AFAIK) unless you decide to write a derived exporter: you can then make `example` blocks produce whatever environment you want (instead of the default `verbatim`). But given that a `#+BEGIN_foo` block is automatically exported as a `\begin{foo}` LaTeX environment, there is no need to bother with an `example` block in the first place.